# How to attach example dataset in R shiny interface?

Tags: r, shiny

I am wondering how to add an example dataset in the place of `Choose file` option in the shiny interface. I am using the `fileInput` option in the `ui` for uploading the user given data in my shiny application. But I like to attach one example dataset which will useful to the user for demonstrating the shiny application.

```
ui <-navbarPage(
  tabPanel("Data",
              fileInput("file1", h3("Choose the data"), accept = c(".xlsx/xls", ".xls", ".xlsx")),
              checkboxInput("sample_data", "Load sample data"),
              fileInput("file2", h3("Choose the group information"), accept = c(".xlsx/xls", ".xls", ".xlsx")),
              checkboxInput("sample_groups", "Load sample groups"),
              actionButton("btn", "Submit"),
              helpText("Note: Upload the .xlsx or .xls file")))

server <- function(input,output, session){
  
  inFile1 <- reactive({
  if (input$sample_data){
    inFile1 <- readxl::read_excel("sample_data.xlsx")
  }
  else{
    inFile1 <- readxl::read_excel(input$file1$datapath)
  }
  })
  
  inFile2 <- reactive({
    if (input$sample_data){
      inFile2 <- readxl::read_excel("sample_groups.xlsx")
    }
    else{
      inFile2 <- readxl::read_excel(input$file2$datapath)
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

I have used the above code. But the example dataset is not uploading while I click the `checkboxInput` button.
And I have saved the example datasets in the `www` folder of working directory.
Please suggest how to edit this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Provide a checkbox labelled "Use sample data" or similar.  When the checkbox is ticked, disable the `fileInput` and load your test data.  Or prefill the `fileInput` with the location of the test data file.  I prefer the first option.

Comment: thank you @Limey for your answer. can you answer me how to edit my code which I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("upload", "Choose a file", accept = ".csv"),
  br(),
  actionButton(
    "takeDataset", "Or use the 'iris' dataset", class = "btn-block"
  ),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("dataSummary")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Data <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input[["upload"]], {
    dat <- read.csv(input[["upload"]][["datapath"]])
    Data(dat)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["takeDataset"]], {
    Data(iris)
  })
  
  output[["dataSummary"]] <- renderPrint({
    summary(Data())
  }) |> bindEvent(Data())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where you load an example data set at the start of your app:

Before, we first create a `my_iris.xlsx` in the root directory (this is your example dataset): with

```
library(openxlsx)

# for writing a data.frame or list of data.frames to an xlsx file
write.xlsx(iris, 'my_iris.xlsx')
```

Then in the server part we use `if/else` to create the placeholder .xlsx while loading:

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx) # for read.xlsx

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose XLSX File", accept = ".xlsx"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    
    if(is.null(input$file1)) {
      
      dat <- read.xlsx(file.path(getwd(), "my_iris.xlsx"))
    } else {
      file <- input$file1
      ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
      
      req(file)
      validate(need(ext == "xlsx", "Please upload a xlsx file"))
      
      dat <- read.xlsx(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    }
    
    dat
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```